# How should I check if the input is an email address in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

According to [RegExp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) documentation, we must use `JavaScript` (`Perl 5`) regular expressions : [ECMA Specification](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects). What method should I use in Dart to check if the input is an email?

Comment: As of 2019: To properly support email validation in Dart/Flutter, please see the pub.dev package email_validator

Comment: As of 2023 there  is a well supported and popular package that provides the best solution:
https://onepub.dev/packages/email_validator

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I'd recommend everyone standardize on the HTML5 email validation spec, which differs from RFC822 by disallowing several very seldom-used features of email addresses (like comments!), but can be recognized by regexes.

Here's the section on email validation in the HTML5 spec:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29

And this is the regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

Comment: That's the same pattern I pasted, but I didn't mark it as code so it was escaped. If it still doesn't validate email addresses, that's something for the W3C to fix :)

Comment: little late, but... It is not work - it`is valid for "s@s" string.

Comment: its valid for a@a

Comment: While that is the one listed on the page, it allows `anything@anything`, which seems like a big oversight since as far as I know there are not any valid email addresses of that form.

Comment: They're all technically valid, according to the standard cf. https://serverfault.com/a/721929/530945

However, [ICANN did establish a rule against dotless domains in 2013.](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en)  [Which Google would like to change.](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/07/12/google_one_word_domains/)

Comment: Beware the new domain extensions e.g. `.services`
```dart
main() async {
 _checkEmail("a@a");
_checkEmail("a@a.a");
_checkEmail("s@asd,com");
_checkEmail("a@aa.co,uk");
_checkEmail("a@a.aa");
_checkEmail("a@aa.aa");
_checkEmail("aa@aa.aa.aa");
_checkEmail("aa.aa@aa.aa.aaaaaaaaa");
_checkEmail("aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaa@aaaaa-aaaaaa.aaaaaaa.aaaaaaaaa");
}

_checkEmail(email){
bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^(?=^.{6,255}$)([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&amp;])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,85}$").hasMatch(email);
  print("${email.toString()} - ${emailValid.toString()}");
}
```

Comment: The regex has been updated in the HTML standard since this answer was posted. The [new one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#email-state-(type=email)) is: RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")

Comment: This answer is straight-up wrong. It doesn't enforce a domain extension and is out of date already.

Answer (score 321):

For that simple regex works pretty good.

```dart
const String email = "tony@starkindustries.com"

final bool emailValid = 
    RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
      .hasMatch(email);
```

Comment: Best answer here. If you can't identify *all* valid emails, it is best to be lenient and not frustrate your users.

Comment: There are many valid characters in the local section, not included in this expression for example, the + operator isn't included such as a+b@c.d additional valid characters include !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ and more are valid given additional restrictions

Comment: For people looking at this as the highest upvoted answer at time of posting, this does not accept `name+filter@domain.com` which is how many users will automatically filter emails in their inbox. So don't use this unless you want to annoy them. If you want the most lenient regex, then use the accepted answer. Simple !== best.

Comment: I am confident that this solution works for 99% of the use cases for general users. Not many users are familiar with `+` feature in email address. Also, disallowing it does not really forbid users from registering on the website. So this answer is fine for majority of use cases.

Comment: Accepting `+` can be more troublesome if your backend system is not smart enough to ignore what comes after `+` when it wants to accept new users by each unique address. It could potentially allow an user to purposefully (or accidently) register to the system when they have already done, because they provided different suffixes (knowingly or without knowingly) after `+`.

Comment: Among other things this regex won't allow hyphens in domain names: qweqwe@qwe-qwe.qw

Comment: @user482594 That's not a valid concern. If the backend wants to eliminate users with the +filter they can just write a 2 line check for that. Anyway I run multiple sites with millions of users and I can tell you just by a quick cursory check it's more than 1%.

Comment: @StackOverflowed I am baffled to hear that it is not a valid concern. What I talked about happens in countless websites and that is how users abuse those systems with a single email address. You will be surprised to see how many systems fail to add that check to filter duplicate registrations.

Comment: @user482594 Failing to check is on the website not the user.

Comment: @StackOverflowed which is exactly what I talked about in the earlier comment :)

Comment: should be the accepted one

Comment: it allows me to use hello@com 
Is it valid email?

Comment: Duplicate character '.' inside character class

Comment: working good....

Comment: Note `test@subdomain.domain.com` will **NOT** work

Comment: Cool but I own a valid email:  xxx@xxx-xx.com so the dash will not pass. 
This will allow '-' in the word after the '@'
RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")

Comment: @GalRom Thanks - nice when people contribute instead of wining

Comment: it is not valid for a@a-a.com

Answer (score 126):

Using the RegExp from the answers by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800541/5411817) and [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888554/5411817),
I made a extension method for `String`:

```
extension EmailValidator on String {
  bool isValidEmail() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

```
TextFormField(
  autovalidate: true,
  validator: (input) => input.isValidEmail() ? null : "Check your email",
)
```

Comment: not ";". it is "," isn't it? but yours are a good idea.

Comment: Yes,thanks for report.I fixed it

Comment: Perfeect, Dart Regexp doesn't work by copy pasting the regex from HTML5, your code has the fixes it needs to work properly, thank you for that! :D

Comment: For anyone coming in the year 2023+ this, in my personal opinion (not that anyone asked, but still :D) might be the best solution for an e-mail validator for **dart**. @763 will correct me if I'm wrong since I'm no regex guru, but on the last part of the regex, you can constrain the length of the domain (i.e.+[a-zA-Z] **{2, _5_ }** ), because the current regex allows you to enter 2> characters (.comcomcomcom, .netnet, .etcetcetc). Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: @GrandMagus I cant say its good or not cause I m not guru at regex too :)

Answer (score 39):

I use this pattern : [validate-email-address-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript). (Remove slash `/` delimiters and add the Dart delimiters : `r'` `'`).

```
bool isEmail(String em) {

  String p = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);

  return regExp.hasMatch(em);
}
```

EDIT :

For more information on email validation, look at these posts : [dominicsayers.com](http://blog.dominicsayers.com/category/email-address-validation/) and [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) .  This tool may also be very useful : [gskinner RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

EDIT : Justin has a better one.  I'm using the pattern he proposed.

Comment: That pattern only accepts TLDs with 3 chars max. There are lots of TLDs bigger than that.

Answer (score 25):

The best regEx pattern I've found is the RFC2822 Email Validation:

`` [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])? ``

Taken from: [regexr.com/2rhq7](http://regexr.com/2rhq7)

All the other regEx I've tested, mark the string `email@email` as a positive, which is false.

Comment: Why is the best answer not this?

Comment: It actually works. I've tested it.

Comment: This allows "email@example.com." which is invalid.

Answer (score 14):

I used a simple and not so rigorous validator which also allows `anything@string.com` and `anything@string.co.in` domains:

```
var email = "tony123_90874.coder@yahoo.co.in";
  bool emailValid = RegExp(r'^.+@[a-zA-Z]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$').hasMatch(email);
  print (emailValid);
```

Comment: Actually you're missing - char for the domain name :)

^.+@[a-zA-Z-]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$

Answer (score 11):

**2019 Correct Answer**

To properly support email validation in Dart/Flutter, please see the pub.dev package `email_validator`.

Source: https://github.com/fredeil/email-validator.dart

_

**This properly supports:**

- TLDs [optionally]
- International Domains [optionally]
- Filtered domains (e.g. user+filter@domain.name)
- Domainless addresses (e.g. user@localhost)

Comment: I like this package, because if I typed `test@test` it would be considered wrong as I want.

Answer (score 10):

Email validation in Dart, follow the Regex:

```
bool validateEmail(String value) {
  Pattern pattern =
      r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
  return (!regex.hasMatch(value)) ? false : true;
}

void main() {
  print(validateEmail("aslam@gmail.com"));
}
```

Flow the below Regex:

```
r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$'
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/aslamanver/3a3389b8ef88831128f0fa21393d70f0

Comment: Doesn't allow "h@h.h" (valid) and allows "!email@example.com" (invalid).

Comment: Do you think h@h.h available to email ?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this page a few times when I was searching, and I came up with a simpler Regex for dart which might help those who will come to this page later.

here is the regex:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

so in `dart` you can use it like

```
RegExp(r'^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+')
```

It only supports normal emails and not without TLD. for instance, me@email.com but not me@localhost. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't match `me@localhost`

Comment: No it doesn't , just normal emails (use for production for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived to this page in search for e-mail validation, but none of the examples found here have passed all my tests.

Therefore I decided to write my own regEx, adapting some of the concepts from other answers (standing on shoulders of giants), and it is doing great so far:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

If you find any issues with that pattern, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The best regular expression i've came across till now is the following:

r'([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_+.]*[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9].(com|net)|([0-9]{1,3}.{3}[0-9]{1,3}))'

this approach relies on adding every domain name you want your user to be able to log in with.

i just added com and net since they are the most popular ones but you can simply add more