# Flutter how to validate password input field with regex

Tags: regex, flutter

I use regex validation in my custom textfield listener, to check if password valid

this is my validation code

```
            RegExp regexUpper = RegExp(r'^(?=.*[A-Z])$');
            RegExp regexLower = RegExp(r'^(?=.*[a-z])$');
            RegExp regexLength = RegExp(r'^.{8,}$');

            if (!regexLength.hasMatch(value.toString())) {
              return 'Пароль слишком короткий';
            }
            if (!regexLower.hasMatch(value.toString())) {
              print(value);
              return 'Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну маленькую букву';
            }
            if (!regexUpper.hasMatch(value.toString())) {
              return 'Введите хотя бы одну заглавную букву';
            }
            return null;
```

regexLength work correctly but other not.

What i did wrong and how i can fix it ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800540/how-should-i-check-if-the-input-is-an-email-address-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You should not use lookarounds wrapped with anchors.

You can fix the issues with

```dart
RegExp regexUpper = RegExp(r'[A-Z]');
RegExp regexLower = RegExp(r'[a-z]');
RegExp regexLength = RegExp(r'^.{8,}$');
```

Look: `^(?=.*[A-Z])$` asserts the current position at the start of string (`^`), then checks if there is an uppercase ASCII letter (`[A-Z]`) anywhere after zero or more chars other than line break chars (as many as possible, with `.*`), and then requires the end of string (`$`) (right at the start of string). This is an example of a pattern that never matches any string.