# How to validate email after @ in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I  validate email after @ in email address ? I need to show error if user input only "username@".

```
String emailValidator(String email, BuildContext context) {
  if (email == null || email.length == 0) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('validators.requiredField');
  }

  if (email == null || !email.contains("@")) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('validators.invalidEmail');
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I check if the input is an email address in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800540/how-should-i-check-if-the-input-is-an-email-address-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

Create an extension on String

```
extension RegexExt on String {
  bool validateEmail() => RegExp(
          r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
      .hasMatch(this);
}
```

Usage

```
String emailValidator(String email, BuildContext context) {
  if (email == null || email.length == 0) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('validators.requiredField');
  }

  return email.validateEmail() ? null : AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('validators.invalidEmail'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use email_validator package of flutter

```
               Form(
                    autovalidateMode:AutovalidateMode.always,
                    child:TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value)=>EmailValidator.validate(value!) ? null : "Please enter a valid email",
                      controller: emailController,
                    ),
                  )
```

email_validator will take email as input and returns true if email is validate or false I have used it with textfield you can also try

```
String email = 'username@gail.com';
bool isValid = EmailValidator.validate(email);

print('Email is valid? ' + (isValid ? 'yes' : 'no'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regex would be the best option for that. Adding a package for this easy task seems like too much overhead for me.

This question has been answered lots of times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800540/how-should-i-check-if-the-input-is-an-email-address-in-flutter)

The expression:

```dart
bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to check email validation

```
static bool isEmailValid(String email) {
 return RegExp(r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')
     .hasMatch(email);
}
```